# Is it common to be able to deadlift more on a hex bar than on a straight barbell?

Tags: deadlifts, barbell

Titular question says it all. Analogous to how barbell bench press typically goes much heavier than dumbbell version of the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This is to be expected.

Yes, it is typical to be able to deadlift more on a hex bar. Because the hex bar has you standing between the plates, the center of mass of the bar is closer to your own. This reduces the length of the moment arm involved in lifting the weight, which means less torque, and so less force, is required to break the floor and get the weight up. Additionally, it often the case that the hex bar is more accommodating to certain anthropometries, allowing people with longer femurs or shorter arms to get into a more favorable starting position than with a straight bar.

Comment: What are anthropometries?

Comment: @Frank Skeleton measurements. Think “human geometry” - were talking about the lengths of your bones, the angles of your hip sockets, that sort of thing. Some people are more “anthropometrically” suited to lift a certain way, meaning the way their skeleton is put together is favorably for certain movement patterns.

Comment: @Frank For example, long arms and short femurs can give you some advantages in the deadlift.